# Meteor Method '/users/insert' not found

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to insert a document in to MongoDB using the following

```
import { Users } from "../../api/users/collection";
Users.insert(UserInfo);
```

but I'm getting this error message "Method '/users/insert' not found"

I create the collection here:

```
import { Mongo } from "meteor/mongo";
export const Users = new Mongo.Collection("users");
```

I have created the users collection using Robo 3t on the server side named "users"

Using this set up I can `.insert()` with other collections but not with the newly created `Users` collection.

Comment: `users` is a reserved collection name - it's part of the *Accounts* package.

Comment: Thanks Michel, I'll be more mindful of my tags from now on. I sincerely apologize. After changing the collection name to "customers" I am still having the same issue,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you I have found the issue

I needed to import the collection in the server side of the start up

For me it looks something like this

```
import { Meteor } from "meteor/meteor";
import { Merchants } from "../../api/merchants/collection.js";
import { Orders } from "../../api/orders/collection.js";
import { Customers } from "../../api/customers/collection.js";
import mockMerchantData from "./mockMerchantData.json";

Meteor.startup(() => {
  // If DB is empty, add mock data
  if (Merchants.find().count() === 0) {
    // Create a new database document for each merchant.
    mockMerchantData.forEach((merchantData, i) =>
      Merchants.insert({
        ...merchantData
      })
    );
  }
});
```